# Installing Inno Setup and AVG and popup error

Tags: inno-setup

AVG always wants to do a 15 second scan on files it doesn't trust. As a result I get this error when the setup begins.

[image: Error]

I can click Ok and eventually the setup will continue.

Is there any way to make this a more friendly user experience? I know I can get my setups added to whitelists But I am referring to this 15 second scan and the message shown to the user.

Infact, when it continues (when being run from Inno) I then get:

[image: Debug Error]

Comment: Is your installer code-signed?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes.

Comment: Maybe you should ask a more generic question with more generic tags ([tag:win32], [tag:windows], etc).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Maybe. See updated question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Unless I get it white listed (which I will not do until I release it) the issue is that Inno extracts a small file first and I think it is that file causes the wobbly. AVG hangs a process for 15 seconds whilst it examines a file.

Comment: I used to get this problem as well (not with Inno Setup, but with other "normal" compilers). But it was happening on the development machine only. Nowhere else. Like if AVG detected that the binary was created on the machine and considered that suspicious (virus-like behaviour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a interesting user [discussion](https://support.avg.com/answers?id=906b0000000DgHNAA0) on the AVG website. In short, one of the users stated:

> Hello, I found the problem, and its pretty easy to fix. Go to the
>   "Settings" option in the menu. In the "General" section there is a
>   tick box for "Enable CyberCapture" - untick it.
>
> CyberCapture just checks programs that are not run a lot, which means
>   if you recompile a program then it "looks" different to AVG, which
>   means AVG things it has not been run a lot, ie its a brand new
>   program, so AVG always does this CyberCapture check on newly compiled
>   programs. Unticking the "Enable CyberCapture" fixes the issue. No need
>   to repair or reinstall anything, it would be nice if the AVG
>   representatives at least had some knowledge of the "General" settings
>   for AVG, that would have saved some time.

I am actually using AVG 19.5 the option was found here:

[image: AVG Settings]

I can confirm that switch this off stops these warnings I was getting.